# Starting WebPageTest.org's test with bookmarklet

Tags: javascript, bookmarklet, webpagetest

I'm trying to start a webpagetest.org's test with a bookmarklet. My bookmarklet code is:

```
javascript:void(window.open(%27https://www.webpagetest.org/?url=%27+window.location.href,%27_blank%27));
```

It opens a webpagetest.org, fills the current page's url into the url field (till now everything correct) - but doesn't start the test.

How is the bookmarklet code to improve to start the test? I need just to trigger a click on <kbd>Enter</kbd>

Answer (score 0):

**I - How to make the code work?**

The code provided won't start. So here are two little tweaks.

1 - The common structure of bookmarklets is called **IIFE**-construction, i.e. Immediately Invoked Function Expression:

```
javascript:(function () {
    /*code here*/
})();
```

2 - The second thing is the encoding, like `%27%` etc, that's why the code won't trigger.

So the right code might be:

```
javascript:(function () {
    window.open('https://www.webpagetest.org/?url='+window.location.href, '_blank')
})();
```

Now the code works, it "opens a webpagetest.org, fills the current page's url into the url field" filled with `window.location.href`, or the URL you are at, the moment you trigger the code.

But it won't press the `Start Test` button at the open page.

**II - How to press `Enter` at the page opened with a bookmarklet?**

**The answer**: You cannot do it with bookmarklet. For at least due to two reasons.

The main reason is that you wish to press `start test` button after opening this new page, but JS (in a stardard way) works only with one web-page. You might need some other tools.

And the second reason is that the site-builder has made it work this way. Moreover, the site may ask to solve captcha upon clicking the button.

**III - Possible solution**

That might exceed the scope of the question. But one of the possible ways to auto-trigger the button on exact site is some **browser addon**, e.g., **tampermonkey or greasemonkey**.

Strategy with the abovemenionned addon: `Wait the page to load. Then if the site with the URL has a non-empty input with exact ID, then press button with an exact tagname`.

Apart from addon there might be some other ways though, depending on the goals.